# arm-linux-androideabi-gcc : get unrecognized command line option when passing -mmacosx-version-min argument

Tags: c++, macos, android-ndk, qt5

I get an error when I'm trying to build Qt 5.5 for Android.
"make" command returns me an error :

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mmacosx-version-min=10.7'
```

I'm building for mac osx 10.10, with ndk version r10e ..

Here is my configure command line :

```
./configure -xplatform android-g++ -nomake tests -nomake examples -android-ndk /Users/John/Android/android-ndk-r10e -android-sdk /Users/John/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk -android-ndk-host darwin-x86_64 -skip qttranslations -skip qtwebkit -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples -no-warnings-are-errors -opensource -confirm-license
```

I just follow this guide : 
http://wiki.qt.io/Android

Comment: Looks like the configure script is broken. It shouldn't be passing that flag.

Comment: Please print full path to arm-linux-androideabi-gcc compiler, it should be used from darwin folder

Comment: @Arseniy The full path is /Users/John/Android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc . So it seems to be correct ..

Answer (score 0):

Try hard code the -mmacosx-version-min with "10.8" or try "10.x" directly